# Apps Script gadget on custom domain shows "We're sorry, but we were unable to locate the page you requested."

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created own apps script gadget in the site and inserted it in a page. When I open the site at http://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.com/www/sms-zprava it works. When I use my custom domain http://www.mydomain/sms-zprava it doesn't. The error "We're sorry, but we were unable to locate the page you requested." is shown. The gadget uses UI API.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=546) and there's no solution for it yet. You should *star* it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.